# How i update scrollviewer after image scaled?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, scale, scrollviewer

I have a big problem in ScrollViewer updated after scaling image. I tried calling method UpdateLayout, but everything intact. The image no problems scaling, but the scrollbars remain unchanged.

A few hours, I look for different solutions here on stack overflow and google, but no I failed.
XAML:

```
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="imagescrl" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanContentScroll="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
            <Image x:Name="imgp"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.01" ScaleY="0.01"/>
                        <ScaleTransform x:Name="imgpScale">
                            <ScaleTransform.ScaleX>
                                <Binding ElementName="sldZoom" Path="Value" Mode="OneWay"/>
                            </ScaleTransform.ScaleX>
                            <ScaleTransform.ScaleY>
                                <Binding ElementName="sldZoom" Path="Value" Mode="OneWay"/>
                            </ScaleTransform.ScaleY>
                        </ScaleTransform>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Image.RenderTransform>
            </Image>
        </ScrollViewer>
    ...
    ...


            <Slider ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged"  x:Name="sldZoom"   BorderThickness="11,20,0,5" Maximum="250" Minimum="1" Value="100" Width="153"/>
```

Thank you

c#:

```
private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender,RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        imagescrl.UpdateLayout();
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

You gonna need to use

```
<Image.LayoutTransform>
```

instead of

```
<Image.RenderTransform>
```

And no need for the event in backend code

Answer (score 5):

[Jim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21028654/234) should be correct, but to explain why:

`RenderTransform` in WPF only affects the final *render* of pixels onto the screen. It doesn't affect the size that WPF thinks things are - if you render transform something down to 50%, and then ask it what it's size is, it will think it's the same size. This means that any panels/scrollviewers you put it in also think it's the original size.

`LayoutTransform` affects the actual size of the object, so if you LayoutTransform something, it will get it's size properties changed, and so the scroll viewer should work

Why are there 2 kinds of transform? Sometimes you only want to affect the rendered output and not change the layout, and also because `RenderTransform` doesn't change the layout, it should be faster as no parent views will need to re-calculate their sizes, etc